Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source(Ubuntu 24.04)
Latitude-3510:~$ sudo apt install wine
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ noble: /etc/apt/keyrings/winehq-archive.key != /usr/share/keyrings/winehq.gpg
Im using Ubuntu 24.04

This question is similar to: "Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source". If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
